# Changing scraped strings (convert to float and back) inside a list

Tags: python, xml, type-conversion, scrape

I'm practicing at scraping websites and I get a string of prices back. I'm not too familiar with lists and how they work so I'm unsure, but I want to convert the USD to AUD which is approximately just a $1:$1.32 ratio. I would assume the string is first eval() to become a list of floats, then possibly just multiplied by 1.32, but I'm unsure how to actually make the ratio exchange however:

```
from tkinter import *
from re import findall, MULTILINE

rss = open('rss.xhtml', encoding="utf8").read()

    # prints 10 price values
regex_test = findall(r'([0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*) USD', rss)
price = ["$" + regex_test for regex_test in regex_test] 
for cost in range(10):
    print(price[cost])
```

That will print 10 prices, where => represents the transition to the next price ie 20 USD becomes 26.40 AUD:

1. $20.00 => $26.40
2. $20.00 => $26.40
3. $20.00 => $26.40
4. $20.00 => $26.40
5. $16.00 => $21.12
6. $23.50 => $31.02
7. $20.00 => $26.40
8. $16.00 => $21.12
9. $189.00 => $249.48
10. $16.00 => $21.12

For the sake of an assistive that pulls prices using the same regex here is a similar rss feed https://www.etsy.com/au/shop/ElvenTechnology/rss

a range of 10 is used as I do not wish to scrape hundreds of entries, just a few off the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made your for loop a bit more pythonic:

```
from tkinter import *k    from re import findall, MULTILINE

rss = open('rss.xhtml', encoding="utf8").read()

    # prints 10 price values
regex_test = findall(r'([0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*) USD', rss)
price = ["$" + regex_test for regex_test in regex_test] 
for individual_price in price:
    print(individual_price)
```

to convert the list into AUD, Assuming you want to just multiply by a value, for your code it seems better to just go back to the list before the dollar sign was added:

```
aud_usd_ratio = 1.32 # 1.32 AUD to 1 USD
aud_price_list = ["$" + str(float(x)*aud_usd_ratio) for x in regex_test]
print(aud_price_list)
```

you could also use string format if you need those two decimal places:

```
aud_price_list = ["${:.2f}".format(float(x)*aud_usd_ratio ) for x in regex_test]
print(aud_price_list)
```

Comment: Did a little changing to what you provided and it worked a treat thx!

Comment: Wonderful! If the tweak is was important maybe  add to the answer so it helps others?

Comment: I updated variable names to be a little more specific, but do you mean something like that?

Comment: oh i meant, it was just in case there was some major tweak that made it work for you that was not in the solution. yes, your edits made it clearer.

Comment: well I guess it slightly helps people how to download a webpage and scrape from it, can't hurt

Answer (score 1):

With a little changing to glycoaddict's solution, a list of updated prices or likewise "variable" can be created in a list, from which each value from the list is then individually called:

```
# installs necessary modules
from tkinter import *
from re import findall, MULTILINE
import urllib.request

# downloads an rss feed to use, the feel is downloaded, 
# then saved under name and format (xhtml, html, etc.)
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.etsy.com/au/shop/ElvenTechnology/rss", "rss.xhtml")
# opens the downloaded file to read from, 'U' can be used instead
# of 'encoding="utf8"', however this causes issues on some feeds, for
# example this particulare feed needs to be encoded in utf8 otherwise
# a decoding error occurs as shown below;

# return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 
# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 12605: character maps to <unidentified>


rss = open('rss.xhtml', encoding="utf8").read()
# regex is used to find all instances within the document which was opened
# and called rss
regex_test = findall(r'([0-9]+[.]*[0-9]*) USD', rss)
# formats the returned string to be modified to desired value (glycoaddict)
# aud_usd_ratio = 1.32 is the same as simply using 1.32, this just creates
# a variable with a value of 1.32 to multuply rather than simply 1.32 itself
AUD_price = ["${:.2f}".format(float(USD)*1.32) for USD in regex_test]
# loops the function 10 times, this is to stop rss feeds with thousands 
# of returns listing endlessly, this only returns the first 10, which are
# taken out of the created and formatted/modified string list, and prints
# each value individually, which is useful for say a list of label
# in tkinter to be looped and placed 
for individual_item_price in range(10):
    print(AUD_price[individual_item_price])
```

note that every time this is run the rss file will be downloaded and updated, meaning that is can be considered live prices, running this now, then an hour or several later will return different results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `regex_test` is identical to my `prices_list_usd`:

```
prices_list_usd = [11.11,12.22,21.324,3.11]
usd_aud_ratio = 1.32
prices_list_aud = [price*usd_aud_ratio for price in prices_list_usd]
combined_list = zip(prices_list_usd,prices_list_aud)
for pair in combined_list:
    print("$USD {0} => $AUD {1}".format(pair[0],pair[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extract all of the values, cast them into float and then format accordingly,

```
# I don't know rss file so dummy variable
rss = "$20.00 => $26.40  $20.00 => $26.40  $16.00 => $21.12  $189.00 => $249.48"

costs = re.findall(r'(?<=\$)\d+\.\d+', rss)

# cast to float and multiply with 1.32
costs = [float(cost) * 1.32 for cost in costs]

# now format them
for i in range(0, len(costs), 2):
    print("{:.2f} => {:.2f}".format(costs[i], costs[i + 1]))

# output

# 26.40 => 34.85
# 26.40 => 34.85
# 21.12 => 27.88
# 249.48 => 329.31
```